# Forming a subset of rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rational function is defined by $$f(x) = \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\dfrac{a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+⋯+a_0}{b_m x^m+a_{m-1} x^{m-1}+⋯+b_0}$$
where $m,n$ $\in\Bbb{N}$ $\cup{\{0\}}$ such that not every coefficient $b_i$ is $0$ and $f(x)$ is not defined at the values of $x$ for which $b(x) = 0$. $$$$What 'special' choice(s) of $b(x)$ will give the result that the set of all polynomial functions, $a(x) =a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+⋯+a_0$ form a subset of the rational functions (as defined above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $b_m = b_{m-1} = \cdots = b_1 = 0$ but $b_0 = 1$ so that $b(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I think $b_1$ is any value other than 0.

Comment: @Icephatom $b_1$ can definitely be zero in a rational function. For example, $\frac{x^2 +1}{x^2+2}$ has $a_1 = b_1 = 0$